# mxGraph editor - fire an event when a node is created

Tags: java, graph, editor, mxgraph

I'm playing with the sample mxGraph editor that comes with JGraph. I have a method which I'd like to be called every time a new node is created. Do you know how to do this?

I have a feeling it has something to do with mxGraphComponent, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the API docs of the `mxGraph` class. It fires a number of granular events to specify what changes have occurred. You are most likely interested in `mxEvent.CELLS_ADDED`. So add a listener with:

```
graph.addListener(mxEvent.CELLS_ADDED, myHandler);
```

where myHandler implements the `mxIEventListener` interface that requires the invoke method to be implemented (your method that gets called when the event is fired).